# GAPI output doesn't match Google Analytics website

Tags: google, php, google-analytics, api

I have to get the main info about my Google Analytics Goals.

I'm using GAPI lib, with this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'conf.inc';
require_once 'gapi.class.php';

$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$dimensions = array('pagePath', 'hostname');
$metrics = array('goalCompletionsAll', 'goalConversionRateAll', 'goalValueAll');

$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, $dimensions, $metrics, '-goalCompletionsAll', '', '2012-09-07', '2012-10-07', 1, 500);
$gaResults = $ga->getResults();

foreach($gaResults as $result)
{
    var_dump($result);
}
```

cut this code is output:

```
object(gapiReportEntry)[7]
  private 'metrics' => 
    array (size=3)
      'goalCompletionsAll' => int 12031
      'goalConversionRateAll' => float 206.93154454764
      'goalValueAll' => float 0
  private 'dimensions' => 
    array (size=2)
      'pagePath' => string '/catalogs.php' (length=13)
      'hostname' => string 'www.example.com' (length=13)
object(gapiReportEntry)[6]
  private 'metrics' => 
    array (size=3)
      'goalCompletionsAll' => int 9744
      'goalConversionRateAll' => float 661.05834464043
      'goalValueAll' => float 0
  private 'dimensions' => 
    array (size=2)
      'pagePath' => string '/price.php' (length=10)
      'hostname' => string 'www.example.com' (length=13)
```

What I see on Google Analytics website on Goals URLs page with the same period of date is:

```
    Goal Completion Location    Goal Completions    Goal Value
1.  /price.php                        9,396            $0.00
2.  /saloni.php                       3,739            $0.00
```

As you  can see outputs doesn't match. Why? What's wrong?